# SAS: Combine YEAR and MONTH data into a single mm/dd/yyyy date without changing types

Tags: date, datetime, sas

**Question:** How do I combine YEAR and MONTH data into a single mm/dd/yyyy date without converting from numeric to character types?

---

I have date data which needs to be read into SAS.  It comes in two columns, YEAR and MONTH.  The data looks similar to this:

```
 YEAR MONTH
 2012 1
 2012 1
 2013 10
 2012 2
 2014 7
```

The data must be stored in mm/dd/yyyy format.  For example, YEAR = 2013 and MONTH = 10 corresponds to 10/01/2013.

I have accomplished this via:

```
if month = 1 then
  date = input(compress("01/01/"||year),mmddyy10.);
else if month = 2 then
  date = input(compress("02/01/"||year),mmddyy10.);
...
```

However, the log gives the following note:

> NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the
>   places given by:
>         (Line):(Column).

I understand that this is being done because SAS stores dates as numeric values since January 1, 1960.  The Compress function returns a character value.  Thus, the numeric data is being coerced into a character type.

While the above code sufficiently solves my problem, the note implies that date formatting should not be handled in this way (via type conversion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `mdy()` function:

```
date = mdy(month, 1, year)
```